# Functions on $c_0$ with special properties

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f:c_0\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a function on $c_0$ (the Riesz-space of all sequences converging to zero). Suppose that $f$ is positive linear and has the following property: **if $g_1,g_2,\ldots$ are functions in $c_0$ such that $g_n\rightarrow0$ then $f(g_n)\rightarrow0$**. I want to prove that $\sum{f(\textbf{1}_{\{n\}})}<\infty$. Therefore i thought that we can use the following lemma: If $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence in $[0,\infty)$ such that $\sum{x_n}=\infty$, then there exists a sequence $(a_n)_n\in[0,\infty)$ with $\sum{a_nx_n}=\infty$ and $a_n\rightarrow0$.

I want to prove the contradiction that $\sum{f(\textbf{1}_{\{n\}})}<\infty$. Thus suppose that the sum is infinity, then there exists such a sequence $(a_n)_n$ as in the lemma. But further i do not come. I think that this is in contradictio with this property of $f$ but i don't see how.

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is the crucial point that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$ missing in the statement of the lemma.

That rectified, if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty f\left(\mathbf{1}_{[n]}\right) = \infty$, let $(c_n)$ be a sequence of nonnegative terms with $c_n \to 0$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\cdot f\left(\mathbf{1}_{[1]}\right) = \infty.$$

Let $c = (c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in c_0$, and for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $\pi_n(c) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n c_k\cdot \mathbf{1}_{[k]}$. Then $c$ and $\pi_n(c)$ are nonnegative elements of $c_0$, and $\pi_n(c) \leqslant c$.

> Therefore $$\sum_{k=0}^n c_k f\left(\mathbf{1}_{[k]}\right) = f(\pi_n(c)) \leqslant f(c)$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But then $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kf\left(\mathbf{1}_{[k]}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(\pi_n(c)) \leqslant f(c) < \infty,$$ contradicting the assumption.